# I'm trying to slice a column in dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
Df['column']
123
567789476
900XXX444ABCJJJ863XXX
0
2748462838583627484
STITISTISTISTIXXXXXXXXXXXX
836XXX738JJJ484ZZZ838ZZZ
33
269EEHHJ
8888
```

I TRIED

```
Df['column']=Df['column'].str[:3]
```

Output

```
Nan
Nan
900
Nan
Nan
STI
836
Nan
269
Nan
```

I tried all possblie way to change the dtype of the column to string but it remains as object only

Comment: why `nan` in output,  why not `123` as I see `900`, how you splitting

Comment: @Akhilesh_IN because `123` is stored as a number, while  `900XXX444ABCJJJ863XXX` is a string

Comment: Correct @Akhilesh

Answer (score 1):

you can force the conversion to string before slicing it

```
 df['column'] = df['column'].apply(lambda : str(x)[:3])
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
df['Column'].astype(str).str[:3]
```

You can see the result here when applied to your data:

```
In[7]: df['Column'].astype(str).str[:3]
Out[7]: 
0    123
1    567
2    900
3      0
4    274
5    STI
6    836
7     33
8    269
9    888
```

You can find more about `astype` in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the data type of a column in a Pandas Dataframe you can use `as type` . Here is the [Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html). Using your example:
`df["column"] = data["column"].astype(str)` . Then, if you want to take only the first three letters or numbers of every row, you can make:

```
for i in list(range(len(df)):
     df.iloc[i][0][::3]
```

Let me know if you have further questions.